# How to do a series of events run by clicks

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want the program to run different functions by click. I don't want buttons, just want it to run with left clicks.
In the code below, it runs `getorigin` by a left click, I don't know how to make it run `other_function` by next left click, and then run `third_function` by one more left click.

```
from tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def getorigin(event):
    x0 = event.x
    y0 = event.y
    print('getorigin:', x0, y0)

def other_function(event):
    print('other function', x0+1, y0+1)

def third_function(event):
    print('third function', x0+1, y0+1)

# --- main ---

# create global variables 
x0 = 0  
y0 = 0

root = Tk()

w = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=640)
w.pack()

w.bind("<Button-1>", getorigin)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the left-click with a function that counts clicks and runs functions based on that.

```
def userClicked(event):
    global clickTimes
    clickTimes += 1

    if clickTimes == 1:
        getorigin(event)
    elif clickTimes == 2:
        other_function(event)
    elif clickTimes == 3:
        third_function(event)
```

You would need to declare that global `clickTimes` as 0 down in your main

Answer (score 0):

You could put the functions in a list, and then rotate the list each time you process a click.

Sometime after you've created the functions, add them to a list:

```
def getorigin(event):
    ...
def other_function(event):
    ...
def third_function(event):
    ...

functions = [getorigin, other_function, third_function]
```

Next, associate a function with a button click that pops the first function off of the list, moves it to the end, and then executes it:

```
def handle_click(event):
    global functions
    func = functions.pop(0)
    functions.append(func)
    func(event)

w.bind("<Button-1>", handle_click)
```